# How to handle date in Python, Sqlite3. the date is stored as vachar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to expose a problem I have with date comparison in Python and Sqlite3, I am trying to filter by dates from a table where I store the date as a Vachar (10) string, here the problem. I appreciate in advance the help or guidance.

Here I get the date of the day and add days to obtain the end date (self.fecha_new1), where it gives me a later date

```
def sumar_dias2(self, *args):
        dias=0
        self.combo=StringVar()
        if self.combo_recordar.get() == "7 Días":
            dias=7
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "15 Días":
            dias=15
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "1 Mes":
            dias=30
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "3 Meses":  
            dias=90
        elif self.combo_recordar.get() == "Todos":
            dias=0
        self.hoy=datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
        hoy1 = datetime.strptime(self.hoy, "%d/%m/%Y")
        self.fecha_new = hoy1 + timedelta(days=dias)
        self.fecha_new1=datetime.strftime(self.fecha_new, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Here I get the current date (today)

```
def convertir_fecha(self):
    self.fecha_hoy=datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    self.fecha_hoy1 = datetime.strptime(self.fecha_hoy, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Here I generate the report, where I try to filter between today's date and the later date, it does not generate an error, it simply does not emit anything. The table is in Sqlite3 and the variable is stored as type Vachar (10)

```
def get_recordatorios_dias(self):
    #Limpiando la Tabla
    records = self.tree4.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree4.delete(element)
    #consultando lo datos
    fecha1=datetime.strptime(self.fecha_hoy, "%d/%m/%Y")
    fecha2=datetime.strptime(self.fecha_new1, "%d/%m/%Y")
    self.fecha11=fecha1.date()
    self.fecha22=fecha2.date()
    print(type(self.fecha11))
    print(type(self.fecha22))
    print(self.fecha11)
    print(self.fecha22)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM recordatorios WHERE date(FECHA_RECOR) BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY    APELLIDO1_RECOR' 
    parameters=(self.fecha11, self.fecha22)
    db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree4.insert('', 0, text = row[0], value=row[1:10]) #, tags='cero')
```

Here I have my query

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
     with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()  
    return result
```

I am handling dates in the format days / month / year, 07/30/2021 and I save it as a string in the table, I use Sqlite3, the problem is that when I want to generate a report, based on date ranges, it does not sort it by date, I have read and tried several options, but I no longer know where to find answers, if someone understands me or has an idea to help, thank you very much.

Comment: Store the dates as YYYYMMDD and then comparisons like greater than and less than will work correctly.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will try that way

Comment: With SQLite always use the format YYYY-MM-DD to store text dates. SQLite's functions like strftime() and date() work only with this format.

Comment: Excellent, I broke my head, I already modified and it worked perfectly, you already had 5 days with this problem, thank you very much, – snakecharmerb, – forpas